Why the pile-on of downvotes for one (somewhat impudent) question?
One recently (June, 2024) asked question from a newer user rapidly received four downvotes.  From what I can tell of the question, the wording was a little off and somewhat impertinent but the question itself indicated a misunderstanding on the part of the OP that can be addressed with a proper answer.
I've seen far more obnoxious questions asked here, where it's clear that the OP is trolling or otherwise pushing some crank, but four downvotes are usually reserved for clear spam or pure garbage.
What gives with this question?  I don't want to fully go to bat for the question per se but I just wanna remind the community of voters to assume good faith..?  Or at least provide a comment as to why the question is deserving of a -1.

"Or at least provide a comment as to why the question is deserving of a -1." -- Why? I don't see why one would have to put work precisely into those questions into which little work went.

Thanks @NorbertSchuch - the effort for putting in a comment along the lines of "you're misunderstanding how this works." I've seen you post some comments on questions or answers that I'm pretty sure you also downvoted; if I've agreed with your assessment I've -1'ed the question and +1'ed your comment.

I think with at least the same justification as "Comment when you downvote" one could argue that if you think a post is good, but not well written, you should make an effort to try to teach the OP how to write it well. However, that happens much less than upvotes on badly written posts occur.

Thanks for the edit @user1271772. I forgot “pile-on” is a North American football saying for a tackle that might not translate worldwide.

Haha, no problem!

Same with “go to bat!”

I'm not sure there's too much to say about it. The question is poorly formatted and unclear. In fact, there's not even an actual question in the body of the post. At the same time, it's not bad enough to get closed, because arguably one can tell, with some fantasy, the actual question that's there. Plus the title might attract relatively many clicks.
So maybe a combination of these factors causes many people to click, see the question, think it's a bad question but not bad enough to close it, and therefore settle with downvoting it instead.
In theory, one should choose to upvote/downvote based only of what they personally think of the question, not based on the current score, so the above is quite sufficient to justify the (currently) 4 downvotes. In practice, that's rarely the case in my opinion (for example, it wouldn't surprise me if the one upvote on this question was caused by the many downvotes more than anything else), but that's another story.
There's certainly questions much worse than this one, but those generally get closed before reaching that many downvotes. Or maybe don't attract enough attention to get as many downvotes.

Thanks. I haven't voted on the question - I'm the +1 for the answer (although it's not great and I have some minor suspicions that ChatGPT might have helped). But (1) the question passed the initial review so at least someone thought it was OK enough to post, (2) the questioner is marked as a "New User" which should counsel being nice, and downvotes, no matter whether they should be or not, are perceived as not nice, (3) it's not clear if the downvoters left any comment about the question and its issues, and (4) downvotes can lead to downvotes just as much as counter upvotes, I think.

@MarkSpinelli I've always had the feeling that downvotes lead on average to increasing the rep. Simply because I think many people are more likely to upvote to counteract downvotes, and if this happens even with a frequency higher than 1/4, it leads to an average rep increase. Then again, I don't really have any data to back this up, so I don't know for sure

@glS I'm willing to bet. Indeed, sometimes I don't downvote for precisely that reason.
